# allowing remote access to subversion

Tags: svn, netbeans, redhat

We have default install of subversion running on redhat.

I've created a repository and added some users in a "passwd" file and updated "svnserve.conf" to point to this.

Now I want to allow these new users to connect from a remote netbeans installation (using the built-in svnkit).

I can only connect using the ssh username/password, but I want to connect with the new accounts I've added (as explained above).

currently, I've tried: svn+ssh://myhost/path/to/repo and (svn://myuser@myhost/path/to/repo) - and as explained, only the ssh accounts work.

So do I *need* to create proper linux accounts for all users? if so, then whats the point of the svnserve.conf options to setup users?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `svnserve` running?

Comment: Yes I do have svnserve running.

Comment: show `netstat -na`, `svnserve.conf`, and results of connecting to `svn://URL-OF-REPO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to split the username and password out of the repository URL as follows:

Repository URL: svn://myhost/repo
User: myusername
Password: mypassword

Note: It didn't take 2 years to solve this. I just hadn't noticed the I had left to question open that long and wanted to close it off.